# Specify the realm object type in run time

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have 3 realm model classes, say `ModelA`, `ModelB`, `ModelC`. All 3 of these models have a param name `fav`.

In my method, I want to fetch the model object (which can be of any of the above 3 types) and update the `fav` param based on `API` response.

```
enum ModelType {
  case ModelA
  case ModelB
  case ModelC
}

func update(type: ModelType, id: Int) {
   let realm =  try Realm()
   if let model = realm?.object(ofType: Object.self, forPrimaryKey: id) {
      do {
          try realm?.write {
          let favourite = FavModel()
          model.favourite = favourite
          realm?.add(model, update: true)
         }
      } catch {}
      return model
    }
     return nil
 }
```

I have an enum which can tell me what kind of model object is it, but not sure how to specify the class name while fetching realm objects `realm?.object(ofType: Object.self, for the primary key: id)`.

The Object.self should be either `ModelA.self`, `ModelB.self`, or `ModelC.self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ModelType` to store your class names in `enum`. Instead, you can use `generics`, that will make your code shorter and simpler.

I suppose that three of these classes has the same parameter because they conform to some protocol or they are inherited from some super-class that has this parameter. If it's a super-class, let say its name is `SuperModel`. In that case, your method should look like that

```
func update<StoredType: SuperModel>(type: StoredType.Type, id: Int) {
    let realm = try? Realm()

    if let model = realm?.object(ofType: type, forPrimaryKey: id)  {
        // handle your model
    }

    return nil
}
```

If your model classes conform to some protocol (let say it's named is `ModelProtocol`) then your method should look like that.

```
 func update<StoredType: Object & ModelProtocol>(type: StoredType.Type, id: Int) {
    let realm = try? Realm()

    if let model = realm?.object(ofType: type, forPrimaryKey: id)  {
        // handle your model
    }

    return nil
}
```

With that you can simply call this method, passing your model type as a parameter

```
update(type: ModelA.self, id: 1)
```